# mouse right click and Save Target As in javascript

Tags: java, javascript

There is any possiblity of automatining the Mouse **"Right Click"** and **"Save Target As"** functionality.

Here in my case I have a href link, on which I have to right click the link and to select the "Save Target As" option, to inetrnally downlaod a text file.

**Question:**

1. Whether it can be done in javascript or in jQuery?
2. There is any other technologies which I can use to do this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at ***Selenium*** (http://www.seleniumhq.org). It helps you automating a web browser.

In the following (*Java*) example I will open the StackOverflow homepage, right click on the *"Questions"* button and then select *"Save target as"*.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Open Firefox
        WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();
        // Go to StackOverflow Homepage
        browser.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");

        // Find the questions button
        WebElement questionsButton = browser
                .findElement(By.id("nav-questions"));

        // Right click, then select "Save As.."
        Actions action = new Actions(browser);
        action.contextClick(questionsButton).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
                .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
                .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
                .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();

        // browser.close();
}
```

As you see I call the method `sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)` 5 times because *"Save target as"* is the fifth entry in the menu. Sorry if the screenshot is in Italian.

[image]

Comment: whether it is possible to automate the mouser right click functionality as well.

Comment: Any sample code links available with you, can you please share it if possible

Comment: I can try implementing a solution in Java but I see you've removed the Java tag from your question.

Comment: sorry for that. I have added once again